# How to mock private class members in a class under test with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a legacy class that I added some methods and need to create some JUnit tests that test only these 4 methods. The class under test has a 1 argument constructor that initializes a string. However, in the constructor calls a private method that initializes several private classes and a datasource using a property file.  The methods that I want to test do not use any of these classes.

I am new to writing JUnit tests and not sure how to mock this private method or if it is possible.
The classes' constructor that is under test is this:

```
public ClassUnderTest(String wlUrl) throws Exception {
try {
    this.url = wlUrl;
    initialize();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

} 
The **initialize()** method is private and instantiates several private classes that I don't use in the methods that I want to test.

```
private void initialize() throws Exception {
    try {
        PropertyManager.getInstance();
        logAdapter = LogAdapter.getInstance(PropertyManager.getProperty("LOG_CONFIG_FILE"));    
        log20 = new ServerLogging20();
        ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(PropertyManager.getProperty("DATASOURCE"));
        setInitialContext(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR instantiating PropertyManager & LogAdapter  - " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mock this private method to test the methods that I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito does not support mocking private methods.
Here is an excerpt from [Mockito's FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods):

> Why Mockito doesn't mock private methods?
>
> Firstly, we are not dogmatic about mocking private methods. We just
>   don't care about private methods because from the standpoint of
>   testing, private methods don't exist. Here are a couple of reasons
>   Mockito doesn't mock private methods:
>
> 1. It requires hacking of classloaders that is never bullet proof and it
>      changes the API (you must use custom test runner, annotate the class,
>      etc.).
> 2. It is very easy to work around - just change the visibility of
>      method from private to package-protected (or protected).
> 3. It requires
>      the team to spend time implementing & maintaining it. And it does not
>      make sense given point (2) and a fact that it is already implemented
>      in different tool (powermock).
> 4. Finally... Mocking private methods is a
>      hint that there is something wrong with Object Oriented understanding.
>      In OO you want objects (or roles) to collaborate, not methods. Forget
>      about pascal & procedural code. Think in objects.

If you really want to mock private methods, look at [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock).